# Command don't return expected value inside .zshrc

Tags: process, zsh, function, exit-status

Trying to run:

```
function which_terminal {
        return (ps -p$PPID | awk "'NR==2'" | cut -d "' '" -f 11)
}
```

inside .zshrc to get a varible with which terminal emulator is running so I can configure different themes for different terminal emulators.

when I run this commmand in command line I get exactly the emulator being used. But when I try to add this to the file I get a error like:

```
which_terminal:1: no matches found: (ps -p16632 | awk 'NR==2' | cut -d ' ' -f 11)
```

can't find where it's wrong, if anyone can help

Comment: Apart from whatever `zsh` syntax you've invoked, the `awk` program will output all rows of the `ps` output since the string `NR==2` is "true".  Drop the inner set of double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, the return value of a function is like the exit status of a command: you can only return a small integer value indicating success (0) or a failure code (> 0).

This status has nothing to do with the output of a command. To run a command and store its output into a variable, use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). To run a command in a function and gets its output as the output of the function, just run the command.

```
function which_terminal {
    ps -p$PPID | awk "'NR==2'" | cut -d "' '" -f 11
}
```

Note that parsing the output of `ps` is unreliable and overkill. (Plus you got it wrong: you're parsing `'NR==2'` to `awk` and `' '` to `cut`, both of which are invalid arguments; you need either single quotes or double quotes around each of these, not both.) The `ps` command has options to print out whatever field you want, e.g. `comm` for the name of the executable (truncated to 16 characters under Linux) or `args` for the full command line with arguments (and sometimes the full path to the command, depending on how it was invoked).

```
function which_terminal {
    ps -p$PPID -o comm=
}
```

Or, to store the output into a variable:

```
parent_process_command=$(ps -p$PPID -o comm=)
```

The reason for the error you're getting is that zsh is trying to parse what follows `return` as an argument of a command (here it's an argument of the `return` keyword, but they're parsed in the same way). It sees an open parenthesis and decides that it's the start of a wildcard expression. That wildcard expression would match a file called `ps -p16632`, `awk 'NR==2'` or `cut -d   -f 11` (with leading/trailing spaces that don't render here), but since you (unsurprisingly) have no files with any of these names, zsh complains that it didn't find a match. `return ?` would return 3 if you happened to have a file called `3` in the current directory and no other file with a one-character name.

Comment: thank you so MUCH for your answer. Just one thing, is it possible to "ps cmd=" return just the name of the terminal? It would be nice

Comment: @ArthurCaccavo What are you calling “the name of the terminal”?

Comment: the command, without the double quotes, was returning in the terminal line just the name of the terminal, "tilix" or "gnome-terminal". The ones I use

Comment: @ArthurCaccavo Your commend was truncated, but now I think I see what you mean: you may prefer `comm` to `cmd`.